# web.py Form.validates() error with utf-8 character in attribute name

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, web.py

I have a form in web.py that displays fine thanks to string.decode('utf-8') but when it submits I get a `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)` from web/form.py in attrget, line 17.

That code looks like this, line 17 is specifically the pass in the except block.

```
def attrget(obj, attr, value=None):
    try:
        if hasattr(obj, 'has_key') and obj.has_key(attr): 
            return obj[attr]
    except TypeError:
        # Handle the case where has_key takes different number of arguments.
        # This is the case with Model objects on appengine. See #134
        pass
    if hasattr(obj, attr):
        return getattr(obj, attr)
    return value
```

It must be something about encoding because the form works if I remove the Swedish ö character. Here is the form definition.

```
searchForm = form.Form(
    form.Textbox('Startdatum', id='datepickerStart'),
    form.Textbox('Slutdatum', id='datepickerEnd'),
    form.Textbox('IPadress', validIPaddress),
    form.Textbox('Macadress', validMacaddress),
    form.Button('Sök'.decode('utf-8'), type='submit', description='Search')
)
```

The third line, calling Form.validates(), is where it is triggered.

```
def POST(self):
    form = self.searchForm()
    if not form.validates():
        headerMsg = 'Du skrev något fel, gör om, gör rätt.'.decode('utf-8')
        return tpl.index(headerMsg, form)

    return tpl.index(headerMsg='Inga rader hittades', form=form)
```

The full traceback is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 239, in process
return self.handle()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 230, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 420, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/application.py", line 396, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
  File "/home/mkbnetadm/netadmin/na.py", line 36, in POST
    if not form.validates():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/form.py", line 76, in validates
    v = attrget(source, i.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.6.egg/web/form.py", line 18, in attrget
    if hasattr(obj, attr):
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So what can I do to avoid this error when creating forms in web.py?

Comment: I don't understand all this use of `'Sök'.decode('utf-8')`. Why not use Unicode in the first place: `u'Sök'`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Using uString works too but does not solve the issue.

Comment: No, I didn't say it would (that's why I posted it as a comment, not an answer). However you do need to show the proper traceback, as the error is clearly not caused by a `pass` statement.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Added full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute names, like all identifiers, must be (convertible to) ASCII:

```
[Python 2.6.6]
>>> foo = object()
>>> hasattr(foo, 'o')
False
>>> hasattr(foo, u'o')
False
>>> hasattr(foo, u'\xf6')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 0:
ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers

Comment: The code I was making was supposed to use jquery eventually for form submission and validation, so I worked around this issue by moving ahead with that and not using the builtin web.py form validation. But since you're probably correct I will mark your post as the answer.